# FreePBX. Check incoming call number in database and and call to specific extension number in organisation

Tags: php, sql, asterisk, freepbx

Can someone tell how to make freepbx work in this way, when there is an incoming call, the system need to check incoming call phone number in database and if there is assigned internal phone number, transfer incomming call to assigned number. If not  just call by default strategy, that was setuped via freepbx

FreePBX 13.0.194.2
Asterisk Version 13.15.0

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You should use CallerID Lookup Sources module from dev repo.

After that you need do custom context which will do forward based on cidname.